# Как обрезать background на css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как обрезать фон, как показано на изображении? сделал background цветом. Низ обрезал с помощью clip-pathа верх никак не выходит. Кто знает - помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 вариант:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:350px;
  margin:50px auto;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: relative;
  transform: skewY(3deg);

}
.content:before{
  content:'';
  display: block;
  background:yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:350px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  top:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

2 вариант:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 13%, 100% 84%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 13%, 100% 84%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

По [clip-path](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) есть онлайн мейкер. Но тут зависит от [поддержки браузеров](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path), нужно это свойство вам или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Углы , маски, трансформация: [Angled Edges with CSS Masks and Transforms](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms/).